# imp database oracle 9i и конфликт с тригерерами

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

База работает 24/7, имеется куча триггеров и расчетов на insert/update.

Вопрос при импорте промежуточных данных в аналогичную базу, будут срабатывать триггеры?
НА время выполнения импорта будут блокироваться таблици для команд DML?

К примеру если есть 1000 insert, взятых из таблици, вставляем в другой базе данных в такую же таблицу с тригерром расчета. Триггеры при вставки через  imp отработают?

Comment: С какой бы радости триггеры срабатывали на изменение других объектов? на чём триггер определён, на то и реагирует.

Comment: По умолчанию таблицы при импорте создаются заново. Откуда там могут быть триггеры?